# ZSH jump to the end of words

Tags: zsh

I have successfully customized my `zsh` to handle the right `WORDCHARS` I want it to. However, when jumping, deleting or autocompleting words, it jumps to the start of each word, I would prefer if it jumped to the end of words instead.

For example in the following command, when jumping using `backward-word` and `forward-word`, the cursor jumps to the positions marked by the `^` characters below:

```
$ kubectl --context stage --namespace kube-system get pods
  ^         ^       ^       ^         ^    ^      ^   ^   ^
```

I would much prefer if zsh jumped to the end of words instead like this:

```
$ kubectl --context stage --namespace kube-system get pods
  ^      ^         ^     ^           ^           ^   ^    ^
```

Is that possible to configure?

Comment: I can't answer your question directly, however I thought I came across this when learning how to fully utilize [Oh-My-ZSH](https://ohmyz.sh/).  Might be worth a look until someone with more knowledge responds =]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```sh
# Replace `forward-word` with `emacs-forward-word`. Problem solved.
zle -A emacs-forward-word forward-word

# For `backward-word`, it's a bit more complex. We'll have to 
# create a new widget for this.
zle -N backward-word backward-word-end
backward-word-end() {
  # Move to the beginning of the current word.
  zle .backward-word

  # If we're at the beginning of the buffer, we don't need to do 
  # anything else.
  (( CURSOR )) ||
      return
    
  # Otherwise, move to the end of the word before the current one.
  zle .backward-word
  zle .emacs-forward-word
}
```

For this version of `backward-word`, there are some edge cases where, if the cursor is positioned to the right of a large amount of non-word characters, it might intuitively feel like it jumps a bit too far. But for the test case you presented above, it works exactly right.

---

For even better word movement and customization options, check out my plugin [Zsh Edit](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-edit).

Comment: Beautiful, thank you so much!

Comment: @FrederikNS If you're interested, I've now released a more advanced version of the above as a plugin: https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-edit#better-backwardforward-kill-word-widgets-with-subword-matching

Comment: Fantastic! I'll definitely give it a try!

Comment: Thank you [insert your god of choice here; or not] for this fix. Annoying default jumping around too far.